# Uploading media to wordpress API with C# HttpClient

Tags: images, uploads, rest-api, media, api

I was trying to save some media but I can't get it to work. I don't know if its the authorization is the wrong format, or if its the content is just put in wrong. If someone knows how to please help me.

```
string url = "http://website.at/wp-json/wp/v2/media";
string filename = "C:\\Users\\Schneider David\\Downloads\\pexels-markus-spiske-3039036-scaled.jpg";
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<username>:<password>"));

var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}" },
    { "Accept", "application/json" },
};

HttpClient client = new();

foreach (var header in headers)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
}

StreamContent streamContent = new(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open));
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("form-data; filename=testtest.jpg");

using var response = await client.PostAsync(url, streamContent);
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL to begin with `https://` - it looks like WordPress authentication only works when TLS is employed, and that's good practice anyway.

Look at the response from the server. It will tell you what's wrong. Add `Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` to the end, and it'll probably print something like

```
    {
        "code": "rest_cannot_create",
        "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
        "data": { "status":401 }
    }
```

Username is the username you use to log in to your wordpress wp-admin site (not the name of your wordpress Application Password). Example: `JoeShmoe`

Password is the Application Password value (not the password you use to log in to your wordpress wp-admin site). Typically expressed as 6 quads with spaces, such as `afev aJbY vrK4 S3Yn fF3R 6cLE`